# Given final block not properly padded AES

Tags: java, javascript, aes, encryption

I am encrypting a string and storing it in a cookie at client side.. but when I send that exact encrypted string from js to java code it gives me the aforementioned exception.

The code I am using for encryption and decryption is:

```
public static final String UNICODE_FORMAT = "UTF8";

public static String encrypt(String Data, SecretKeySpec skeySpec,IvParameterSpec ivspec) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivspec);
        byte[] plainBytes = Data.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plainBytes);
        String encryption = bytesToString(encrypted);
        return encryption;
}

public static String decrypt(String encryptedData,SecretKeySpec skeySpec,IvParameterSpec ivspec) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivspec);
    byte[] decryptval = hexToBytes(encryptedData);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(decryptval);
    return new String(decrypted);
}

public static String bytesToString(byte[] bytes) {
    HexBinaryAdapter adapter = new HexBinaryAdapter();
    String s = adapter.marshal(bytes);
    return s;
}

public static byte[] hexToBytes(String hexString) {
    HexBinaryAdapter adapter = new HexBinaryAdapter();
    byte[] bytes = adapter.unmarshal(hexString);
    return bytes;
}
```

can you tell me what the issue could be?? I have tried the solutions mentioned at stackoverflow.com and also a few other solutions but none worked.. am I getting this error because I am sending the encrypted string to JS and it is changing the padding of the string?

Comment: Does it work when you run encypt / decrypt both on server side?

Comment: yes it does work then... the problem is only when I return it back from the javascript

Comment: `new String(decrypted, UNICODE_FORMAT)` but that cannot be the error.

Answer (score 0):

As @ JoopEggen mentioned - creating sting from byte[] can break it.

Can you just serialize, instead of creating string from it?